# System.DllNotFoundExeption has been thrown (Xamarin,MonoGame,and XNA)

Tags: xna, xamarin, monogame

I installed XNA 4.0, the latest version of Xamarin, and the latest version of MonoGame. I loaded up a brand new Open GL solution and got this error.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'openal32.dll': The specified module 
could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) ---> System.Exception:

at at OpenTK.Audio.OpenAL.Alc.OpenDevice(String devicename)

at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController..ctor()

at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController.get_GetInstance()

at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor(Game game)

at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create(Game game)

at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor()

at dgsdgsdgdsg.Game1..ctor() in   
c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Projects\dgsdgsdgdsg\dgsdgsdgdsg\Game1.cs:0

at dgsdgsdgdsg.Program.Main() in 
c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Projects\dgsdgsdgdsg\dgsdgsdgdsg\Program.cs:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [installing OpenAL](http://code.google.com/p/rallyraid/downloads/detail?name=oalinst.zip&can=2&q=)...

The link points to the the installer for OpenAL.

Comment: Just as an FYI - the OpenAL link no longer works. I have no idea where you can download it now.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I swear the link was working, it seems creative have been doing some website work. I used to always grab the binaries form here when I needed them. Found another link to the installer, have edited the url. Regards

Comment: Thanks! I just got around to commenting,but I installed a trusted version of Open AL, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your video drivers.

MonoGame is pretty picky about what OpenGL version you have installed. I don't know exact version required (it has changed over time) but refer to [this discussion](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998) for more information.

You can also download the [OpenGL caps viewer](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100806/gpu-tool-gpu-caps-viewer-1-9-0-with-opengl-4-tessellation-support/) to determine which version you are currently running.